# Problem with retrieving Subclasses in a Registry/Dictionary of the Superclass

Tags: c#

I have created two different classes. The first class is the "Item" class, which has a few variables like name and description corresponding to an Item. I then added the "HeadItem" class, which inherits the Item class and adds a bit of different functionality and another variable.

When I put the HeadItem into the Registry/Dictionary of type Item (By registry I just mean something that you can put an ID into and it will return an object corresponding to that ID. Basically just a dictionary with a bit of extra functionality I have added) everything works fine because it inherits "Item," but in another class when I want to get the item of id "head" from the
registry I have to retrieve it as such: HeadItem item = ItemRegistry.Get("head") as HeadItem.

Now this was fine at first. If I ever needed a head item I could just retrieve it as a HeadItem, but now I have implemented a user inventory, and a /give command.

I want to be able to give the player any item from the Registry of items, but that means in the /give commands functionality I will have to say Item item = ItemRegistry.Get(id).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make sure to ask *one* question per question on SO. I've removed unnecessary text and second question (presumably "how to read dictionary from JSON when it serialized with multiple derived classes"). Feel free to do your own research about serialization and if you could not find an answer post it as separate question. Avoid adding historical/personal notes to your future posts (more detailed guidance - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). Also it is generally good idea to show actual code ([mre]) as it often helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you explain why `Item item = ItemRegistry.Get(id).` is a problem? I don't see the issue.